# How to create a manytomany relation in django to models with different data type primary key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model whose primary key is of Integer field datatype and I want to have a manytomany field inside it of another model whose primary key is of Char field.

```
class A(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    link = models.ManyToManyField(B, null=True)

class B(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36)
```

When I used this method I got this error:

```
(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

I got to know that a association table is required, but don't know how to apply it.

Comment: Should be like this class B(A):.